# Dealing with Com Object Terminating Error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Ok, here is the problem, randomly the LoadFiles option doesn't like a certain input file and produces an error. This error is always a terminating error and I cannot figure out any way to get it to continue. Any Ideas?

```
Function ProcessImage {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$File
    )

    If ($Excluded_Owners -notcontains $(get-acl -path $File.FullName).owner) {                                         #Check owner of the file and compare it to list of blacklisted file owners.
        Try{
            $Image = New-Object -ComObject Wia.ImageFile
            $Image.LoadFile($File.fullname)
        } Catch{
            LogWriter -OutPut "File Failed Process File in WIA - `"$($File.fullname)`""
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
            continue
        }

        If($Image.width -gt $PictureMinWidth -or $Image.height -gt $PictureMinHeight) {                                #Check image dimensions.
            IF ($Script:Copy) {
                $CopyTryCount = 0
                While ((Test-Path -Path "$CopyDir\$($Script:MF_ImagesCopied + 1)$($File.extension)" -PathType Leaf) -EQ $False -AND $CopyTryCount -le 3) {           #After the script says the picture was copied without error, verify it indeed was.
                    $CopyTryCount++
                    Try {
                        Copy-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination "$CopyDir\$($Script:MF_ImagesCopied + 1)$($File.extension)" -Force                                    #If the picture meets all requirements, attempt to copy the image.
                    } Catch {
                        LogWriter -Status "Failure" -Output "File Failed to Copy (Attempt $CopyTryCount) - `"$($File.fullname)`""
                    }
                }
                IF (Test-Path -Path "$CopyDir\$($Script:MF_ImagesCopied + 1)$($File.extension)" -PathType Leaf) {                                         #Check the CopyDir directory for the image.
                    LogWriter -Status "Success" -Output "File Successfully Copied - `"$($File.fullname)`""             #If the image was copied successfully, log that.
                    [Int]$Script:MF_ImagesCopied += 1
                    $Temp_ProcessImage_Success=$True
                } Else {
                    LogWriter -Status "Failure" -Output "File Failed to Copy after 3 tries - `"$($File.fullname)`""    #If the image was not copied successfully, log that.
                    [Int]$Script:MF_ImagesFailed+= 1
                }
            }
        } Else {
            LogWriter -Status "Skipped" -Output "Incorrect Dimensions - `"$($File.fullname)`""
            [Int]$Script:MF_ImagesSkipped += 1
        }
    } Else {
        LogWriter -Status "Skipped" -Output "Excluded Owner - `"$($File.fullname)`""
        [Int]$Script:MF_ImagesSkipped += 1
    }
}#End ProcessImage
```

This is the troublesome error.

> ProcessImage : Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "The
>   segment is already disca rded and cannot be locked. " At
>   L:\MediaFinder.ps1:400 char:83
>   +         If ($Images -AND $ImageFileTypes -contains "*"+$*.Extension) {ProcessImage <<<<  $*} 
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,ProcessImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have caught the terminating error in a catch block and turned it into a non-terminating error. That's the first important step. BTW the `continue` in your catch block may also be causing premature termination. `Continue` is meant to be used with loops and with the `Trap` statement.  Remove it and replace with a `return` statement.

The reason your function doesn't process any other files is that it isn't written quite right. So the second step is to put your script in a process block so it can process each `$File` object passed down the pipeline e.g.:

```
function ProcessImage {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $File
    )

    process {
        try {
            if ($file -eq 'foo') {
                throw 'kaboom'
            } 
            else {
                "Processing $file"
            }
        } 
        catch {
            Write-Error $_
            return # can't continue - don't have valid file obj
        }
        "Still processing $file" 
    }
}
```

And if I run the above with these parameters, you can see that it processes objects after the one that throws a terminating error:

```
C:\PS> 'bar','foo','baz' | ProcessImage
Processing bar
Still processing bar
ProcessImage : kaboom
At line:1 char:21
+ 'bar','foo','baz' | ProcessImage
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,ProcessImage

Processing baz
Still processing baz
```

Comment: I simply added changed continue with return and the script runs flawlessly now, thank you. As for the "Process" block, what advantages does using a process block have? I have seen it in a number of different scripts but I am not sure I see an advantage of using it.

Comment: The process block is required if you want to process more than the just the last pipeline object when your function is used in a pipeline (like my example usage above demonstrates).  When you don't specify a begin/process/end block, PowerShell just puts all your script into an `end` block for you.  That script block only gets executed once as the pipeline is finishing executing.  If you want your command to be called for *each* object in the pipeline then you need to put the relevant code inside a `process {}` block.  Your $File parameter inside that block will be updated for each new object.